# Any suggestion of server side frameworks to combine with angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a project that was assigned last week and the basic idea is to make an app with a social component (like, following, messaging, and so on).

To build this app I'm decided that I'll use angularJS, ionic and cordova (I loved the stack and these guys are doing a awesome job).

So, the thing is, this app with have a bit of database interaction and server side scripting, and I'm still trying to find my best option on this.

I'm comfortable with codeigniter, so at first I thought of using it on the server side (for file ,database and so on handeling) and build from there a restful api or even use silex or slimframework  but, as always, it's better to ask.

PS: I'm not the typical lazy coder, I would gladly build the framework for myself but I'm a bit on schedule here so probably I'll have to get some of the work above mentioned done for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CakePhp, Laravel 4.2 and above, codeigniter

Comment: Laravel framework can be used to build application and if you want to build just a websites u can use cakePhp and codeigniter also u can use Yii2 with angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest Laravel 5.1.It has a huge library, a very good resource Laracast to learn this and check how it works with angularjs.

Comment: Not a bad ideia, I've also considered Laravel for that same reason but I've been lazy about learning Laravel, maybe I'll make a short course on that and check how it works .

Comment: It will hardly take some hours to finish laracast series and as you are familiar codeigniter, You can complete it in few hours .

Comment: True, just checked the laracast series and other courses and I won't have the time.

Comment: I hope you can find a better option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to php you should user or Laravel 5.1 or CakePHP 2.*/3.*

Also if are not used to php, you can try Django, Ruby on Rails or ASP.NET

Comment: I'm tottally used to php, it's my main language, I'm considering Laravel. I'm not too familiar either with Laravel but I might give a shot on Laravel - t will be a good oportunity to learn something.

Thanks in advance